# Undefined/null reference when trying to add ReactCSSTransitionGroup (TypeScript + React + JSPM)

Tags: reactjs, typescript, jspm

I am new to React and have been trying to add a very basic animation to a test page to check to know that I understand the processes involved… unfortunately I don’t.

I have installed from what I think are the correct typings, an extract from the automatically generated typings > index.d.ts file is:

`/// <reference path="globals/react/index.d.ts" />
/// <reference path="globals/react-addons-css-transition-group/index.d.ts" />`

I have set-up the JSPM config file with the correct entry, as there are no issues when using React without any animations; the map section contains the following entry:

`"react": "npm:react@15.1.0\\dist\\react-with-addons"`

The index.tsx file is very simple, consisting of (please ignore the run code snippet, for some reason I couldn't use the backticks to insert the multiline codes below):

```js
/// <reference path="../typings/index.d.ts" />
import * as React from 'react';
import * as ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

let ReactCSSTransitionGroup = React.__Addons.CSSTransitionGroup;

ReactDOM.render(<div><ReactCSSTransitionGroup transitionName="example" transitionEnterTimeout={500}>
<h1 key="helloKey">Hello</h1>
</ReactCSSTransitionGroup></div>, document.getElementById('app'));
```

Using the TypeScript compiler produces the following output for index.js:

```js
System.register(['react', 'react-dom'], function(exports_1, context_1) {
    "use strict";
    var __moduleName = context_1 && context_1.id;
    var React, ReactDOM;
    var ReactCSSTransitionGroup;
    return {
        setters:[
            function (React_1) {
                React = React_1;
            },
            function (ReactDOM_1) {
                ReactDOM = ReactDOM_1;
            }],
        execute: function() {
            ReactCSSTransitionGroup = React.__Addons.CSSTransitionGroup;
            ReactDOM.render(React.createElement("div", null, React.createElement(ReactCSSTransitionGroup, {transitionName: "example", transitionEnterTimeout: 500}, React.createElement("h1", {key: "helloKey"}, "Hello"))), document.getElementById('app'));
        }
    }
});
```

When attempting to load the file using the above JavaScript I receive the following error:

`TypeError: Unable to get property 'CSSTransitionGroup' of undefined or null reference at execute (eval code:15:13) Error loading http://localhost:8000/index.js`

When I remove all the animation references then everything works as expected.

I’m certain I’ve made a very simple mistake but I’ve spent hours trying to find out the cause but have not succeeded.  Please note that I have searched on StackOverflow, Google and Bing for assistance, but strangely I can’t find anything similar.

Any help would be greatly appreciated,

Kind Regards,

John

Comment: Could not get this to work. I am not using _react-with-addons_ but build a bundle with _browserify_ and _tsify_ and I get `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'CSSTransitionGroup' of undefined`. Just doing `import ReactCSSTransitionGroup = require("react-addons-css-transition-group")` however does work but looks like there's no type checking on that import.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for your reply.  I managed to get this to work by adding the react-global and react-addons-transition-group typings, the generated typings file now includes the following entries:

```
/// <reference path="globals/react/index.d.ts" />
/// <reference path="globals/react-global/index.d.ts" />
/// <reference path="globals/react-addons-transition-group/index.d.ts" />
/// <reference path="globals/react-addons-css-transition-group/index.d.ts" />
```

Answer (score 0):

[As per the documentation](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/animation.html#high-level-api-reactcsstransitiongroup), you should actually be importing [`react-addons-css-transition-group`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-addons-css-transition-group):

```ts
import ReactCSSTransitionGroup = require("react-addons-css-transition-group");
```

Answer (score 0):

Nowadays, the correct package to include is `react-transition-group`:

```
import { CSSTransitionGroup } from 'react-transition-group';
```